# What caused this splotchy pattern in my Portra 400 Scans? (Epson V600)

Tags: film, post-processing, scanning

I recently started using a Fuji GW490 with Portra 400 film. Having got the film developed, some of the areas out of focus (or smooth gradient areas) appear to have a 'splotchy' pattern of lighter dots that doesn't necessarily look like normal film grain. Perhaps the film is underexposed/expired? Possibly it could be how the lab handled it as I had a few other rolls come out fine.

I scanned using an Epson V600 with Epson Scan software, 48-bit TIFFs.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that you won't ever see grain as sharp as you expect it (https://forums.negativelabpro.com/t/is-this-normal-grain-for-portra-400/4190/21) with that scanner, which can achieve about 1500 dpi *effective* resolution when scanning at 3200 dpi due to poor internal optics/focusing https://www.filmscanner.info/en/EpsonPerfectionV600Photo.html

Answer (score 1):

The diffuse dot patterns look like emulsion reticulation. It is damage to the emulsion usually caused by heat during development, but can also be an artifact of old film.

They don't look like scanner artifacts because the dust and hairs on the scan are perfectly sharp.

Have you looked at the original with at least a 20x loupe? Reticulation would be evident at that magnification.

If you can see something through the loupe, you can try cleaning the emulsion with PEC-12 and re-scanning. It's unlikely to be dirt from the looks of it, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

This is backing paper mottling, which sometimes happens with expired or badly stored 120 film. Heat and/or condensation is the cause. Something (presumably ink) is leeched from the backing paper onto the film, and it affects either exposure or development.

Occasionally, issues with quality control can make this problem happen or at least make the film more susceptible to it. Ilford [issued a statement about this problem a couple of years back](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/updated-120-roll-film-statement/), and Kodak had some trouble for a while as well when they switched to a different backing paper.